# rails-breadcrumb and I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, breadcrumbs

I run into an issue with [rails-breadcrumb](https://github.com/fesplugas/rails-breadcrumbs) since i localized my application.

In my Controller, I've got this :

```
class FooController < PrivateController
  add_breadcrumb I18n.t('breadcrumbs.foo.index'), :foo_url  
end
```

When my breadcrumb is displayed, the localized string is always taken from `en.yml`, no matter which language i set up in `I18n.locale`

After having look at the code, it occurs that `add_breadcrumb`acts as a `before_filter`, and after some test, i came to the conclusion that, even if the content of `add_breadcrumb` has the right locale, it seems that the value passed does not.

If I try this :

```
add_breadcrumb I18n.t('breadcrumbs.foo.index', :locale => "fr"), :foo_url
```

Everything goes fine.

How cas i force my string to be correctly localized?

Thank you per advance

Answer (score 1):

I finaly got this. After i determined that my issue cames out of the fact that I18n didn't know anything about my locale as i was asking it to translate something, i monkey-patched the rails-breadcrumb to manage the localization itself.

Know i pass a Symbol as first parameters, and i call `I18n.translate()` in rails-breadcrumb

```
add_breadcrumb (:'breadcrumbs.foo.index'), :foo_url
```

d

```
# config/initializers/rails-breadcrumb-fix.rb
module Rails
  module Breadcrumbs

    class ActionController::Base

      protected

      def add_breadcrumb(name, url = '')
        @breadcrumbs ||= []
        # if given `name` is a Symbol, we localize it
        if name.is_a?(Symbol)
          name = I18n.t(name)
        end
        url = send(url) if url.is_a?(Symbol)
        @breadcrumbs << [name, url]
      end

      def self.add_breadcrumb(name, url, options = {})
        before_filter options do |controller|
          controller.send(:add_breadcrumb, name, url)
        end
      end

    end

    module Helper

      def breadcrumbs(separator = "&rsaquo;")
        @breadcrumbs.map do |txt, path|
          link_to_unless (path.blank? || current_page?(path)), h(txt), path
        end.join(" #{separator} ").html_safe
      end

    end

  end
end

ActionController::Base.send(:include, Rails::Breadcrumbs)
ActionView::Base.send(:include, Rails::Breadcrumbs::Helper)
```